# Error 403 When Accessing symbolic links

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, webserver, symbolic-link

I create a block storage in Digital Ocean and copy my API to this storage and then create a symbolic link in my /var/www/html which goes to /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/api_cms, but when I try to access an internal folder, such as api_cms/uploads from the browser, I get error 403 and in the apache logs the message "symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible apache2".

How can I make sure I can access the folders and files stored in the API from the browser and consequently from the application that uses this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem by just setting apache2 (www-data) as the "owner" of the /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/api_cms folder and its subfolders, after which it started working normally.